# Why can't I get an array length after I split a string in google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, variable-length

In Google script, after I split a string, I can't then get the length of the resulting array. I guess it's not an array? If so, how can I turn it into an array with a length value?

```
function splitAndCount() {
  str = "33,34,35"; //example string
  var stringSplit = str.split(","); //split string
  return stringSplit.length(); //
  // TypeError: Cannot call property length in object 33,34,35. It is not a function, it is "number". 
}
```

Comment: `length` is not a method, but a number property. No parentheses. The error really says it all. It is a number, not a function. so `stringSplit.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a function, it's property

```js
function splitAndCount() {
  str = "33,34,35"; //example string
  var stringSplit = str.split(","); //split string
  return stringSplit.length
}

console.log(splitAndCount())
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove parenthesis from stringSplit.length, it's not function

```
function splitAndCount() {
  str = "33,34,35"; //example string
  var stringSplit = str.split(","); //split string
  return **stringSplit.length**; 
}
```